# Spherical Geometry Distance Between 2 Points

Tags: spherical-geometry, mathematical-astronomy

I try to calculate distance between 2 points on Earth. I have an a car and this car goes with speed 100 km/h and I know the start point latirude and longitude and car goes 5 hours. I want to calculate "How far has the vehicle traveled?". Actually answer is so simple I know distance = speed * time . However does this rule apply to spherical geometry? I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it is just a trick question. Or it wants you to calculate the displacement?

Comment: No I want to calculate distance. There is an point A and B on the Earth. A car start from A with speed 100km/h and after 5 hours it reaches the B point. So what is the distance between A and B?

Comment: @ Shubham Johri Well how can I calculate the displacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vehicle is traveling along the surface of the sphere, then yes: $distance = speed * time$.